# Can I have a dynamic url with the Google oAuth API?

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-signin, google-oauth

I use the oauth api for login on my sites. Right now if a user needs a site based on a subdomain (user.mysite.com) I have to manually add it in the console so the login button will work at that new domain. The console says you can't use a wildcard such `*.mysite.com`. Is there way way to make this dynamic or a way to add a site programmatically?

I use a tool to create the subdomains and if I could add it to the list of approved domain when upon creation that would be great.

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem?